# How to add an existing module to a hook?

Tags: php, hook

Ive created a new hook and I want to add an existing module (homefeatured) to that hook. The hook's name is: top2
I've added this to homefeatured.php at the bottom of the page:

```
function hookdisplayTop2($params) {
return $this->hookhome($params, 'displayTop2');
}
```

And here I've added the hook in order for it to be available for installing:

```
    if (!parent::install()
|| !$this->registerHook('displayHome')
|| !$this->registerHook('displayTop2')
|| !$this->registerHook('header')
|| !$this->registerHook('addproduct')
|| !$this->registerHook('updateproduct')
|| !$this->registerHook('deleteproduct')
)
```

Also, in the header.tpl file I've added this:

```
<div id='myCustomHook'> {$HOOK_displayTop2} </div>
```

but nothing happens. Of course, I've also added a new row for this hook.
Do you know how to solve this problem? After I click Transplant module for that module (homefeatured) the site is no longer available and it goes blank.

Comment: What version of prestashop do you use?

Comment: Try [what is hook in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379757/best-way-to-do-php-hooks) and [Best way to do PHP hooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379757/best-way-to-do-php-hooks).

Answer (score 0):

**If you use PS 1.5**

Change your function with this

```
function hookDisplayTop2($params) {
    return $this->hookDisplayHome($params);
}
```

And in header.tpl

```
<div id='myCustomHook'> {hook h='displayTop2'} </div>
```

Comment: it worked, but I don't understand why it looks so out of scale now. Everything seems weird. Here, see how it looks now: http://oi58.tinypic.com/1585yp.jpg

Comment: Where in the image should it appear?